# failed to load view for file:///D:/Go: err: go resolves to executable in current directory (.\go): stderr:

Tags: go, language-server-protocol, gopls

I use neovim and emacs on Windows10, Install through MSYS go install golang.org/x/tools/gopls@latest

but emacs eglot & nvim lspconfig show:

```
[eglot] Connected! Server `gopls' now managing `go-mode' buffers in project `Go'.
[eglot] Server reports (type=4): Loading packages...
[eglot] Server reports (type=3): Error loading packages: err: go resolves to executable in current directory (.\go): stderr: 
[eglot] Server reports (type=1): Error loading workspace folders (expected 1, got 0)
failed to load view for file:///D:/Go: err: go resolves to executable in current directory (.\go): stderr:
```

Comment: Are you sure Go is on your MSYS PATH variable?

Comment: There was a change in Go 1.19: golang.org/x/sys/execabs https://github.com/golang/go/issues/43724